# C# Unity Поиск объекта в списке с помощью Linq

Tags: c#, unity3d, linq

Вот у меня есть список объектов моего класса. Мне нужно найти один объект из списка, который будет удовлетворять условию. Список это коллайдеры, нужно найти самый ближайший коллайдер к другому объекту на сцене. Это конечно можно написать через цикл, а через Linq это скорее всего будет работать медленнее, но мне интересно. Я почитал что там есть Where, Select, Find. Дошел до такой вещи.

```
Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(itemHodler.position, sphereRadius, mask);
Collider collider = colliders.ToList().Select(x => Vector3.Distance(itemHodler.position, x.transform.position)).Min();
```

Но это мне вернет значение типа float самую короткую дистанцию, а мне нужен сам collider. Получается надо как-то скомбинировать эти Where, Select, Find. Но я не знаю как.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если этот код будет выполняться часто, например в `Update()`, то не соверую юзать Linq, потому что он может оказаться медленным и просаживать производительность игры. Если не часто будет выполняться, то ок.

Что касается запроса из кода, то `.ToList()` можно и нужно выкинуть. Linq для массивов работает точно так же как и для списков.

Проблему решает простая сортировка.

```cs
Collider collider = colliders
    .OrderBy(x => Vector3.Distance(itemHodler.position, x.transform.position))
    .First();
```

Вот этот код будет быстрее, вынесите в отдельный метод, если страшно в основном коде кучу циклов держать

```cs
private Collider FindClosestCollider(Colliders[] colliders, Vector3 position)
{
    Collider result = colliders[0];
    float min = Vector3.Distance(position, result.transform.position);
    for (int i = 1; i < colliders.Length; i++)
    {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(position, colliders[i].transform.position);
        if (distance < min)
        {
            min = distance;
            result = colliders[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Это вещь выполняется по кнопке, не каждый кадр. Ну и вопрос чисто из любопытства. Без сортировки аналогичный результат получить можно? Что будет выполнятся быстрее, сортировка или Select().Min(). Ваш вариант для конкретной ситуации наверное лучший, но допустим я буду искать опять же объекты (не один) да еще в диапазоне каких-то значений. @aepot

Comment: @FreezeMatic `Min()` возвращает себя, а не объект. Если надо быстро по алгоритму поиска минимального и найти сразу объект, то используйте цикл, как я выше показал.

Comment: Через цикл то понятно, меня интересовала реализация через Linq. Скажем вот [такое](https://sun9-42.userapi.com/impg/P_tZxUfjN3U-CddYOgtDBE0I0h0k_1tbUkgyXA/9mjM3BcHhIc.jpg?size=1207x416&quality=96&sign=b2f0653ddca4508515e5f0d10d3ea6c9&type=album) через Linq можно?

Comment: @FreezeMatic проще простого `colliders.Where(x => Vector3.Distance(position, x.transform.position) is float d && d > min && d < max).ToArray();`. Еще всегда предпочитайте массив вместо списка там, где возможно.

Answer (score 1):

Самый быстрый вариант поиска ближайшего:

```
public static class TransformExtension 
{
    public static Transform FindClosest (this Transform target, Transform[] objects)
    {
        Vector3 targetPosition = target.position;
        int closeIndex = 0;
        float minSqrtRange = (objects[0].position-targetPosition).sqrMagnitude;
        for (int i = 1; i < objects.Length; i++)
        {
            float sqrtRange = (objects[i].position-targetPosition).sqrMagnitude;
            if (sqrtRange < minSqrtRange)
            {
                minSqrtRange = sqrtRange;
                closeIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return objects[closeIndex];
    }
}
```

Используя `sqrMagnitude` не придется совершать тяжеловесные операции по вычислению квадратных кореней, как в `Vector.Distance`. То есть значения расстояния недовычесленны, но что бы их сравнивать это и не нужно.